# Unexpected behavior of ndb Structured Property

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am using ndb Structured property in my app. The models look like this:

**Resource External Integration:**

```
class ResourceExternalIntegration(ndb.Model):
  integration_type = ndb.StringProperty()
  external_resource_type = ndb.StringProperty()
  external_resource_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  external_group_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  external_resource_name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

**Resouce Model:**

```
class Resource(ndb.Model):
  owner = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  type = ndb.StringProperty()
  external_integrations = ndb.StructuredProperty(ResourceExternalIntegration, repeated=True)
```

Note that i have structured property as `repeated=True`

**Issue:**
I have a function in Resource class which formats/serializes the data extracted from DB. It looks like this:

```
    def serialize(self):

    external_integrations_list = []
    if self.external_integrations:
        for external_integration in self.external_integrations:
            external_integration_dict = dict()
            external_integration_dict['integration_type'] = external_integration.integration_type,
            external_integration_dict['external_resource_type'] = external_integration.external_resource_type,
            external_integration_dict['external_resource_id'] = external_integration.external_resource_id
            external_integration_dict['external_group_id'] = external_integration.external_group_id
            external_integration_dict['external_resource_name'] = external_integration.external_resource_name
            external_integrations_list.append(external_integration_dict)

    resource_data.update(dict(
        owner=self.owner,
        name=self.name,
        type=self.type,
        external_integrations=external_integrations_list

    ))
    return resource_data
```

Now, in the `resource_data` the attribute `external_integrations` should be an array and every element in it should also be an array i.e. `external_resource_id`, `external_resource_type` etc should also be an array. It is because of the fact that structured property was set as `repeated=True`. But, the `resource_data` does not contain this expected result. It looks like:

{'name': u'Scissors lift', 'type': u'Scissors', 'external_integrations': [{'external_resource_type': (u'FLEET',), 'integration_type': (u'ABC',), 'external_resource_id': 212017856321402L, 'external_resource_name': u"Test 1", 'external_group_id': 5000}],'owner': 5629490125014563L}

And, on browser it looks like this:

```
external_group_id: 5000
external_resource_id: 212017856321402
external_resource_name: "Test 1"
external_resource_type: ["FLEET"]
integration_type: ["ABC"]
```

i.e. the `external_group_id`, `external_resource_id`, `external_resource_name` does not appear as array, but they were expected as arrays.

I also have another model in which the structured property does not exists as `repeated=True`. It looks like:

**External Integration**

```
class ExternalIntegration(ndb.Model):
  access_token = ndb.StringProperty()
  group_ids = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)
```

**Profile**

```
class profile(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  integration_info = ndb.StructuredProperty(ExternalIntegration)
```

Here, the serialize function of profile model show result as:

{'integration_info': {'group_ids': ([5000],), 'access_token': (u'blahblahblahblah',)}, ''name: 'Test'}

And, on browser the result looks like:

```
access_token: ["blahblahblahblah"]
group_ids: [[5000]]
```

I am unable to understand why `access_token` appears as an array and why `groups_ids` is an array of array.

Can anyone please help me understand such behavior of ndb structured property? Specifically the cases i explained above.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here:

Regarding the **profile model**:

integration_info contains two elements defined in `ExternalIntegration` class. It is saved as a dictionary containing two elements: `access_token` and `group_ids`. `group_ids` is defined with `repeated=True`, [which takes a list of values of the underlying type](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#repeated), which creates a list. To summarize:

1. access_token appears as a string.
2. group_ids appears as a list, because `repeated` is set to `True`.

Regarding the **resource model**:

1. `external_integrations` appear as a list, because you defined `repeated=True`.
2. There is only one element on the list because the whole dictionary was appended in a single operation, instead of element per element.
3. `external_group_id`, `external_resource_id` and `external_resource_name` don't appear as an array because they were not defined with `repeated=True`. The definition is applied one level above, to `external_integrations`, not to each of its contained strings.

Try to redefine the elements which should be repeated and the ones that shouldn't.